# Crystalreport for Visual Studio 2019 and Web Server requirements

Tags: crystal-reports

can somebody let me know what version of Crystal Report is compatible with Visual Studio 2019 and web server MS-2012 R2? can you please list all requirements?
currently the only way the report works is click on "Report Preview" in opened RPT file in VS-2019.
If I run the project on developer machine it shows blank page.
if I publish the project to web server it show "Connection failed"
if I change the database connection in RPT file to remote SQL sever and publish project to web server it works fine.
any help would be appreciated

Answer (score 0):

The issues resolved when I copy ASPnet_Client folder to the root of my published project and then add the following tag to all my ASPX pages that using RTP file.